# Reproducing exact same physics simulation

Tags: ios, game-physics, scenekit

I'm running a physics simulation on a box. When node stops, I change it's position, set it's rotation and apply force. All those 3 parameters are **always** the same, yet the physics simulation is **different**. Difference in not big, but surely noticeable. How do I avoid this and reproduce exact same physics simulation every time? Thanks for help

```
/// this code gets executed repeatedly
        starNode.physicsBody?.velocity = SCNVector3Zero
        applyForce() ///always the same
        starNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0, Float(90*(M_PI)/180.0), 0)
        starNode.position = SCNVector3Make(-0.562, 5.578, -18.529)
```

Comment: Can you try it with 3 different nodes(startNode1, startNode2, startNode3)? also, I think applyForce function call needs to be at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There are minute differences between the timings of the callings of applyForce() and when you set the velocity.

If you have some amount of drag, gravity or any other force influencing the physicsBody's velocity between when you set its velocity and when you apply the force, there'll be a slight difference in the outcome because applying a force to an object with any velocity is additive.

So each time the box slows down a little bit more or less before the force is applied, you get a slightly different result in that addition of the force applied.

Comment: In other words, there is no way to reproduce exact same physics simulation?

Comment: No, you can replicate physics simulations repeatedly, infinitely. But you do need to consider the implications of time deviances in between events in order to get rid of undesirable results.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't know what should I do. How does someone consider implications of time deviances?